# How to fix 'Segmentation Fault(core dumped)' error when reading characters from two input files?

Tags: c, arrays, input, command-line-arguments

I am in the process of writing an encryption program but have come to a halt because of the error: 'Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped)'. The below program is suppose to print from two input files:

The first input file: should be read in and then change the upper case characters to lower case characters and lower case characters to upper case characters.

The second input file: should be read in and just print the number of times the user desired character appears in the file. In this case the user desired character I want is the letter 'a'.

Let's say for example the first input file(input.txt) contains: 
Hello My Name is Joe

This should print as: hELLO mY nAME IS jOE

Let's say for example the second input file(keys.txt) contains:

A

M

This should just print the character: A

*NOTE* This doesn't necessarily encrypt the input file yet however, i'm trying to get familiar with using more than one input file at once. I can use all the help I can get! THANK YOU!

ALSO, when compiling, the code should look like this:

gcc myProgram.c

./a.out e input.txt keys.txt

(The above 'e' just stands for encryption.)

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>


 int main(int args, char *argc[]){

 int i,c,x,len,len2;
 char str[1024];
 char str2[500];
 FILE *finp;
 FILE *keyFile;

 /* ****** CODE TO ENCRYPT STARTS HERE ****** */
 if((argc[1]="e")&&((finp = fopen(argc[2],"r"))==NULL)
 &&((keyFile=fopen(argc[3],"r"))==NULL)){

 printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argc[2]);
 exit(1);

 }//End First IF statement


/* *** START CODE TO GRAB FROM 1st INPUT FILE: input.txt *** */
/*Grab strings from first input file and change lower case to upper case and         
upper to lower case*/

 while(fgets(str,1024,finp)!=NULL){

  len = strlen(str);
  for(i>0;i<len;++i){
  if(((str[i]>=64)&&(str[i]<=90))||((str[i]>=97&&(str[i]<=122))))
  str[i]^=32;}}
  /* *** END OF CODE FOR 1st INPUT FILE **** */



  /* *** START CODE TO GRAB FROM 2nd INPUT FILE: keys.txt **** */
  /*Grab character from second input file and print the character*/

  while(fgets(str2,500,keyFile)!=NULL){

  len2 = strlen(str2);
  for(x>0;x<len2;++x){
   if(str2[x]=='A'){
   putchar(str2[x]);
   }}
   /* ***** END CODE FOR 2nd INPUT FILE*** */


   }


   printf("%s\n",str);

   fclose(finp);
   return 0;}
```

Comment: Are thou speaking of a simple 'return 1'?

Comment: You never initialize `x` or `i` in the `for` loops.

Comment: Could you explain what condition you are speaking of in my if statement that is very wrong? I understand now what you mean about 'argc[1]="e"' being wrong.

Comment: @iharob `argc[1]="e"` is guaranteed to be true if `argc` is writable, as opposed to `argc[1]=="e"` which would be guaranteed to be false. (However `argc[1]="e"` has undefined behavior because the array isn't guaranteed to be writable.) Aside: Raoul, don't use nonstandard names like that — the standard parameter names are `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, and using `argc` for the array of arguments and `args` for the number is really confusing.

Comment: @Gilles I didn't notice the assignment operator the first time.

Comment: Note: this: 'int main(int args, char *argc[]){' while workable is not the standard way of writing a main statement. rather use: 'int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  where argc is the count of args and argv[] is the vector of character pointers to the actual arguments.  the code, before checking the contents of any parameters needs to check the value in argc (in this case, it should be 4)  However, to check for the contents of argv[] use if( strcmp( argc[1], "e" ) == 0 )  then the first argument is a 'e'

Comment: each call to fopen should be separately checked, to enable telling the user of the program exactly which call to fopen failed.   The code needs to check that each argument actually exists (the first argument == 4) and if that is not true, then print  a 'usage' statement to let the user know what is wrong.

Comment: this line: 'for(i>0;i<len;++i){' should be: 'for( i=0; i<len; ++i ){' (I added spaces for readabillity.  The first parameter of a for() statement is the initialization.  i>0 is a condition, not an initialization.

Comment: the 'if()' statement has lots of hardcoded values(almost always a bad idea to use hardcoded values other than 0 and 1)  also, by #include <ctype.h> the macros toupper() and tolower() and isupper() and islower() are available, (or you would write your own at the beginning of your program (or in a suitable header file))  then the actions of the program would be greatly enhanced for visibility, clarity, etc.  suggest using #define statements for 'magic' numbers and then using the #defined names in the code.  This is especially true for the magic numbers that are defining the sizes of the arrays.

Comment: for human readability of the code, strongly suggest: 1) only one statement per line. (no '}}' sequences) 2) indent the code after each opening brace '{' (suggest 4 spaces) 3) un-indent the code before each closing brace '}'  4) do not use any tabs for indentation of the code.  (because each editor/wordprocessor has the tab stops/tab width set differently)\

Comment: there are two file descriptor pointers open, so there needs to be two calls to fclose(), one call for each open file descriptor pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem in your code is that you have not initialized `i` and `x` before using them.

Replace the line

```
  for(i>0;i<len;++i){
```

with

```
  for(i=0;i<len;++i){
  //  ^^^ i = 0; not i > 0;
```

and replace the line

```
     for(x>0;x<len2;++x){
```

with

```
     for(x=0;x<len2;++x){
     //  ^^^ x = 0; not x > 0;
```

You can clean up the code at the start of the function. The logic used in

```
 if((argc[1]="e")&&((finp = fopen(argc[2],"r"))==NULL)
 &&((keyFile=fopen(argc[3],"r"))==NULL)){

 printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argc[2]);
 exit(1);

 }//End First IF statement
```

is wrong on many accounts. Replace that with more readable code:

```
if ( strcmp(argv[1], "e") == 0 )
{
   if ( (finp = fopen(argc[2],"r")) == NULL )
   {
      printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argc[2]);
      exit(1);
   }

   if ( (keyFile = fopen(argc[3],"r")) == NULL )
   {
      printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argc[3]);
      exit(1);
   }
}
else
{
   // Decide what you want to do when the first argument is not "e".
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```
(argc[1]="e")
```

should be

```
!strcmp(argv[1], "e")
```

Same kind of mistake for `argc[2]` and `argc[3]`.

Remember, `argc` is of type `int` (not array). `argv[]` is of type `char *`.

That said, you should always check for the `argc` value against `n` befire making use of `argv[n-1]`.

Then, please keep in mind, the second operand of `&&` is evaluated only if the first operand yields a *TRUE* value. You shoule check the logic you're using in

```
  if((argc[1]="e")&&((finp = fopen(argc[2],"r"))==NULL)
                                &&((keyFile=fopen(argc[3],"r"))==NULL))
```

I don't think it serves the purpose you want it to serve.

Also, as pointed out by Mr. **@iharob**, you never seem to initialize the counter variables used in either of your `for` loops. This will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I've attempted to fix my code with the code you've suggested and receive the well-known 'bus-error(core-dumped)'. What is the significance of this?

Comment: @RaoulDuke There are much other mistakes. Look for the updated answer.

Comment: @dear downvoter, with a kind comment from your side, I stand a chance to correct and improve my answer. Please consider leaving one.

Answer (score 1):

You have many many errors

1. The first `if` statement, is completely wrong

   1. The `argc[1] = "e"`, is wrong from many points of view, first you cant compre strings with the `==` operator, but you didn't use the comparison operator, it's the assignment operator and you can't assign to arrays, so it's twofold wrong.
   2. You used the `&&` operator to check if both files where `NULL` at the same time, which would be false if only one of them is, making the code that follows invoke undefined behavior, possibly causing the **SEGMENTATION FAULT**.
2. You never check if the program was invoked with the correct number of arguments, but you still access the `argc` array, which by the way is normally `argv`, `argc` is used for the number of parameters i.e. where you used `args`, but that doesn't actually matter.
3. Your `for` loops are also wrong

   ```
   for (i > 0 ... )
   ```

   you never initialize the `i`, also a little bit of knowledge of how strings work in c, would make a c programmer to write the following loop to traverse the string

   ```
   for (i = 0 ; ((str[i] != '\n') && (str[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
   ```

   since `fgets()` will read the trailing `'\n'` inserted by pressing the <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> key and thus flushing standard input, you need to check against `str[i] == '\n'` but if you are paranoid you should also check for `'\0'` I am paranoid and I do check although that is ineficient, I prefer to do it instead of seeing unexpected things later.

Here is a sample of your program without the mistakes, I don't know if it does what you want but it's the same program just with errors that could lead to **SEGMENTATION FAULT** corrected

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argb[])
{
    int   i;
    char  str[1024];
    char  str2[500];
    FILE *inputFile;
    FILE *keyFile;

    if (argc < 3) /* insufficient number of parameters provided */
        return -1;
    if (argb[1][0] == 'e')
        return 0;
    inputFile = fopen(argb[2], "r");
    if (inputFile == NULL)
     {
        printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argb[2]);
        return -1;
     }
    keyFile = fopen(argb[3], "r");
    if (keyFile == NULL)
     {
        printf("Could Not Open file %s\n", argb[2]);

        fclose(inputFile);
        return -1;
     }

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), inputFile) != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0 ; ((str[i] != '\n') && (str[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
        {
            if (((str[i] >= 64) && (str[i] <= 90)) || ((str[i] >= 97) && (str[i]<=122)))
                str[i] ^= 32;
        }
    }

    while (fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), keyFile) != NULL)
     {
        for (i = 0 ; ((str2[i] != '\n') && (str2[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
         {
            if (str2[i] == 'A')
                putchar(str2[i]);
         }
     }
    printf("%s\n", str);

    fclose(inputFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I give you much props. This code complies fine and runs. However, nothing is printed even with the printf("%s\n", str); at the end. Why?

Comment: I said in the post, that I don't know if it will work, and I really suspect that the input files are missing or something similar, add `printf()`'s at the exit points where error checking is done, and you will know what is happening.